# Regex to split string into groups

Tags: c#, regex

How can I match this string in c# using regex so it returns 4 groups per line?

1 or more digits|one or more letters|one or more letters|one ore more X-Digit(s)\n

Example:

```
123|ABC|ABC|X-1;X-12;X-13
123|ABC|ABC|X-1
```

I've tried this
\d+\|(A-Z)\|(A-Z)\|(X-)d+

Comment: Have you considered using `text.Split('|')` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shooting with canons at birds?=! If you could simply use the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method to achieve that

```
string test = "123|ABC|ABC|X-1;X-12;X-13";

string [] groups = test.Split('|');
```

it will return an array of elements that were separated by a `|`